# expands shorthand notations like 1-3 in the string to array of strings in C

Tags: c

Lets say I have a string XYZ1-3.

I would like to convert it to a array of strings.
XYZ1,
XYZ2,
XYZ3.

is there an elegant way to do it in C?

Comment: "is there an elegant way to do it in C?" - Yes.

Comment: show us the elegant way, Maroun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char **expand(const char *string, int *num){//num : out var
    char *id = strdup(string);
    int start, end, len;
    sscanf(string, "%*[A-Z]%n%d-%d", &len, &start, &end);
    id[len] = '\0';
    *num = end-start+1;
    char **array = malloc(*num * sizeof(char*));
    for(int i=0;i < *num ;++i){
        len = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%s%d", id, start + i);
        array[i] = malloc(++len);
        sprintf(array[i], "%s%d", id, start + i);
    }
    free(id);
    return array;
}

int main(){
    int n;
    char **array = expand("XYZ1-3", &n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
        printf("%s\n", array[i]);
        free(array[i]);
    }
    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Allow the non-alphabetical(not A-Z) id part

```
#include <ctype.h>

int id_length(const char *string){
    //return length of id part.
    int i, len;
    for(i=0;string[i];++i);
    if(i==0)return 0;
    for(i=i-1;isdigit(string[i]) && i>=0;--i);
    if(string[i]!='-') return 0;//bad format
    for(i=i-1;isdigit(string[i]) && i>=0;--i);
    return i+1;
}

char **expand(const char *string, int *num){//num : out var
    char *id = strdup(string);
    int start, end, len;
    len = id_length(string);
    sscanf(string+len, "%d-%d", &start, &end);
    id[len] = '\0';
    *num = end-start+1;
    char **array = malloc(*num * sizeof(char*));
    for(int i=0;i < *num ;++i){
        len = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%s%d", id, start + i);
        array[i] = malloc(++len);
        sprintf(array[i], "%s%d", id, start + i);
    }
    free(id);
    return array;
}
```

Comment: But lets say I have another peculiar scenario where the initial part of the string could have numbers. i.e XY1Z1-2(The output of which should be XY1Z1,XY1Z2), then obviously this code fails.

Answer (score 1):

Try this--

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
void main()
{
int len,i,c,d,p,j;
char arr[50];
char arr2[50];
char arr3[30][30];
char temp[30];
scanf("%s",arr);
len=strlen(arr);//calculating length of entire input
for(i=0;i<len;i++)
{
    if(arr[i]!='-')
        arr2[i]=arr[i];//arr2[] will hold the string without the numeral
    else
        break;
}
c=(int)arr[i-1]-48;//char is converted into int
d=(int)arr[i+1]-48;
for(i=0;i<len-3;i++)
    temp[i]=arr2[i];
p=0;

for(i=c;i<=d;i++)
{
    temp[len-3]=(char)(i+48);//int is converted into character

      for(j=0;j<=len-3;j++)
          arr3[p][j]=temp[j];//this 2d array holds array of strings
p++;
}

for(i=0;i<=(d-c);i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<=len-3;j++)
    {
        printf("%c",arr3[i][j]);//printing the strings one by one
    }
    printf("\n");
}


getch();
}
```